# Remove DOM Warning PHP

Tags: php, dom

I have this code:

```
$strhtml = file_get_contents('05001400300320100033100.html');
$dochtml = new DOMDocument();
 $dochtml->loadHTML($strhtml);
 $elm = $dochtml->getElementById('upPanelActuciones');
 print $dochtml->saveXml($elm);
```

Im getting this warning:

```
      Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: error parsing attribute  name in Entity, line: 674 in C:\AppServ\www\video01\sector2\dom3.php on line 10

      Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Opening and ending tag mismatch: div and td in Entity, line: 1019 in C:\AppServ\www\video01\sector2\dom3.php on line 10

      Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Opening and ending tag mismatch: div and td in Entity, line: 1020 in C:\AppServ\www\video01\sector2\dom3.php on line 10

      Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Opening and ending tag mismatch: div and td in Entity, line: 1022 in C:\AppServ\www\video01\sector2\dom3.php on line 10
```

I can't manipulate the html (i Know that the html file have errors) so there is a way to remove this warnings? (no show).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> DOMDocument is very good at dealing with imperfect markup, but it
>   throws warnings all over the place when it does.
>
> This isn't well documented here. The solution to this is to implement
>   a separate aparatus for dealing with just these errors.
>
> Set libxml_use_internal_errors(true) before calling loadHTML. This
>   will prevent errors from bubbling up to your default error handler.
>   And you can then get at them (if you desire) using other libxml error
>   functions.
>
> You can find more info here
>   http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.libxml.php

The correct way to deal with DOMDocument errors is this:

```
<?php

// enable user error handling
var_dump(libxml_use_internal_errors(true));

// load the document
$doc = new DOMDocument;

if (!$doc->load('file.xml')) {
    foreach (libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
        // handle errors here
    }

    libxml_clear_errors();
}

?>
```