# How to use extract data from this string

Tags: php, regex

I am not good at writing pattern to extract data. 
I have long document, and below is the specific string that I need to extract.

```
<p><span id="minPrice">XXXX<a href="YYYYY" target="_blank"><span>&yen;ZZZZZ</span></a></span>
```

I want to extract `XXXX, YYYY,` and `ZZZZ` value.

My first step is to get `XXXX<a href="YYYYY" target="_blank"><span>&yen;ZZZZZ`

```
$pattern = '/<p><span id="minPrice">^</span></a></span>/';
preg_match($pattern, $data, $matches);
echo ($matches[1]);
```

But it does not work.
So how to extract `XXXX, YYYY, and ZZZZ` :(

the document that i have is full of error encoding chars so that I can not use loadHTML. It just returns error.

UPDATE 1: So I am able to do

```
        var_dump(libxml_use_internal_errors(true));
        $DOM = new DOMDocument;
        $DOM->loadHTML($data);
        $items = $DOM->getElementById('minPrice');
```

And $items is

```
 DOMElement Object
(
    [tagName] => span
    [schemaTypeInfo] => 
    [nodeName] => span
    [nodeValue] => 最安価格(税込)：¥131,649
    [nodeType] => 1
    [parentNode] => (object value omitted)
    [childNodes] => (object value omitted)
    [firstChild] => (object value omitted)
    [lastChild] => (object value omitted)
    [previousSibling] => 
    [nextSibling] => (object value omitted)
    [attributes] => (object value omitted)
    [ownerDocument] => (object value omitted)
    [namespaceURI] => 
    [prefix] => 
    [localName] => span
    [baseURI] => 
    [textContent] => 最安価格(税込)：¥131,649
)
```

The html is

```
<span id="minPrice">
    �ň����i(�ō�)�F
    <a href="http://kakaku.com/shop/1115/?pdid=K0000693648&lid=shop_itemview_saiyasukakaku" target="_blank">
        <span>&yen;131,649</span>
    </a>
</span>
```

How can I extract `http://kakaku.com/shop/1115/?pdid=K0000693648&lid=shop_itemview_saiyasukakaku` and `131,649` ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

Comment: Regex is not the correct tool for parsing an HTML/XML instead  you can use DOMDocument

Comment: the document that i have is full of error encoding chars so that I can not use loadHTML. It just returns error.

Comment: @John: Did you try to declare `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` when reading the HTML in?

Comment: @John have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783760/remove-dom-warning-php), it might help you approach it correctly

Comment: thanks. trying now....

Comment: So I updated my progress. Can you help me to continue?

Comment: See [this demo](https://ideone.com/AcPpDq) - does it work for you?

Comment: Thanks. It works. Can you write it as an answer. I will mark it.

Comment: I added my solution and added an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code line to enable internal error handling for the DOM parser:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
```

Then, you can access the data you need with this sample code:

```
$html = <<<DATA
<p><span id="minPrice">最安価格(税込)：<a href="http://kakaku.com/shop/1115/?pdid=K0000693648&lid=shop_itemview_saiyasukakaku" target="_blank"><span>&yen;131,649</span></a></span>
DATA;

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$spans = $xpath->query('//span[@id="minPrice"]');   // Get all spans with ID=minPrice
$a = array();
foreach($spans as $span) { 
    foreach($span->childNodes as $child) {          // Check the child nodes
        if ($child->nodeName == "a") {
            array_push($a, $child->getAttribute("href"));
        }
    }
    array_push($a, preg_replace('~^.*?(\d+(?:,\d+)*)$~u', '$1', $child->nodeValue));
}

print_r($a);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://kakaku.com/shop/1115/?pdid=K0000693648&lid=shop_itemview_saiyasukakaku
    [1] => 131,649
)
```

I used a regex to extract the number at the end of the string, but you can use an `explode` with the yen symbol, too.

```
$num = explode(html_entity_decode("&yen;"), $child->nodeValue)[1];
array_push($a, $num);
```

See [another demo](https://ideone.com/KPLC4r)

Answer (score 0):

Use this Regexp -

```
/<p><span.*id=\"minPrice\">(.*)<a.*href="(.*?)".*>.*<span>.*;(.*?)<\/span>.*/
```

Result -

1. `XXXX`
2. `YYYYY`
3. `ZZZZZ`

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with regular expressions and the regular expression to get that exact match is :

```
$regex = "/<p><span id=\"minPrice\">(.*?)<a href=\"(.*?)\" target=\"_blank\"><span>&yen;(.*)<\/span><\/a>/";
preg_match($regex, $data, $matches);
```

However, as mentioned in the comments, regex is not an appropriate tool to do this task. This regex will probably fail if the document is long and nests these matchable patterns (i.e. if XXXX is another one of these paragraphs). You should probably see how you can fix this document to make it proper XHTML and then use a proper XML parser. You can mitigate this by running this regex on each line of input (assuming it's split into lines properly), but still, not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Man use it and sorry for my bad english! 
[PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)
and [download lib](https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/)
This alternative. 
Code:

```
require_once '/simple_html_dom.php';

//here put content or block or DOM  
$html = str_get_html('<p><span id="minPrice">最安価格(税込)<a href="YYYYY" target="_blank"><span>&yen;ZZZZZ</span></a></span>');
//OR
//USE get_file_content if need
//$html = file_get_html('example.html');
//select links, and use first element
$link = $html->find('p span#minPrice a',0);//select links, and use first element
//get url
$href =  $link->href;
//get text in span
$span_in_link = $link->find('span',0)->plaintext;
//delete <a></a>
$link->outertext = '';
 //get text in span
$span_id_minPrice = $html->find('p span#minPrice',0)->plaintext;
//delete  &yen;
$span_in_link =  str_replace('&yen;','',$span_in_link);
 //result
echo $span_id_minPrice.'<br>';//最安価格(税込)
echo $href.'<br>';//YYYYY
echo $span_in_link.'<br>';//ZZZZZ
```

if you have this  > 1, then use it:

```
 //select all span
$html = str_get_html('
            <p><span id="minPrice">XXXX<a href="YYYYY" target="_blank"><span>&yen;ZZZZZ</span></a></span>
            <p><span id="minPrice">XXXX2<a href="YYYYY2" target="_blank"><span>&yen;ZZZZZ2</span></a></span>
            ');
    $all_span = $html->find('p span#minPrice');
     $data = array();
    foreach($all_span as $element)
    {
        $array = array();
        $link = $element->find('a',0);//select links, and use first element
        //get url
        $href =  $link->href;
        //get text in span
        $span_in_link = $link->plaintext;
        //delete a
        $link->innertext = '';
        //get text in span
        $span_id_minPrice = $element->plaintext;
        //delete  &yen;
        $span_in_link =  str_replace('&yen;','',$span_in_link);

        $array['span#minPrice'] = $span_id_minPrice ;
        $array['href'] =  $href;
        $array['span_in_link'] =  $span_in_link;

        $data [] = $array;

    }

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($data);
```

Result:

Array
 (

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [span#minPrice] => XXXX 
        [href] => YYYYY
        [span_in_link] => ZZZZZ 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [span#minPrice] => XXXX2 
        [href] => YYYYY2
        [span_in_link] => ZZZZZ2 
    )
```

)